# Integral along different loops on torus gives a full lattice in $\mathbb C$

Tags: differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

Let $S$ be a compact Riemann surface we $g=1$, $\alpha,\beta$ be the generator of $\pi_1(S)$, $\omega\neq 0$ be a fixed holomorphic $1$-form. How can we know $\int_\alpha \omega$ and $\int_\beta \omega$ are $\mathbb R$-linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by [de Rham's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=De_Rham%27s_theorem). (Which is used in the proof that the Abel-Jacobi map is an isomorphism.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $g=1$, $\omega$ is a basis of $H^{1,0}(S)$. Fix a point $x_0$, and let $\Lambda$ be the lattice spanned by $\int_\alpha \omega$ and $\int_\beta \omega$. Then the Abelian-Jacobian map
$$S \to \mathbb C /\Lambda \\
x \mapsto(\int_{x_0}^x \omega,\int_{x_0}^x \omega)$$
is an isomorphism. In particular $\int_\alpha \omega$ and $\int_\beta \omega$ form a $\mathbb R$-basis of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Isn't the Abel-Jacobi theorem a bit overkilled for this question ? In fact I think usual proof of the Abel-Jacobi theorem uses this fact.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Yeah I agree.